# OnScrollChange событие

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, javascript-events, scrollbar

В JS есть event listener scroll `.addEventListener('scroll', function(){})` Оно работает пока страница скроллится, есть ли событие как с инпутом к примеру onchange, то есть после того, как скролл остановится, вызывать функцию? Если нету, можно ли подобное реализовать? (я пробовал через setTimeout, но может есть варианты лучше?)

Comment: Это поможет?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620906/how-do-i-know-when-ive-stopped-scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример:

```
var timer = null;

document.on('scroll', function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    alert('прокрутка прекратилась');
  }, 100);
});
```

Проверить можете прописав эти строчки в консоли браузера и попробовав прокрутить страницу